# Tracing optimization for ES6 class with d8

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, v8

I have a nodejs application where I have a module which internally uses an ES6 class. I would like to trace this module with d8 to spot possible un-optimizable code. Meaning, there is a calculation process implemented in this module and I'd like to make it faster, to achieve this I'd like to analyse the code first, hence d8.

I tried

```
d8 --trace-opt my-nodejs-file-with-es6-class.js
```

The problem is that I don't get a (good) output. First it notifies me about require statements, then if I comment them out I get zero output. I also tried `--trace-deopt` as well as `--trace-opt-verbose`. I don't know what the problem could be.

- I am expecting to get an output like: xy function can be optimized or xy function could not be optimized due to TryCatchStmt, etc..
- It might be that my file needs an entry point?! Currently this file is part of my application and since the module is practically an ES6 class, othermodules will call the calculation.

Any advice how could I possibly measure this module's, or that particular function's performance?

Comment: You can't run node.js code in d8 (i.e. d8 simply does not have `require` and other stuff). Furthermore you don't need to use d8 to get optimization information - you can just pass the very same flags to node, e.g. `node --trace-opt` should work.

Comment: Additionally you should start by looking at profile for you application before you start digging into optimization information. Always profile first to establish hotspots. The fact that some function is optimized or not-optimized does not tell you much if you don't know if this function is on the hot path or not.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with nodejs cli flags ;)